# What does the IMAP banner alone show regarding security (STARTTLS, hashing, information disclosure)?

Tags: hash, email, imap, starttls, information-exposure

I encountered an open TCP/143 IMAP port which responded with this banner:

```
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE LITERAL+ STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 AUTH=CRAM-MD5] Dovecot ready.
```

From this I figures the following three things:

#### 1. STARTTLS is available but optional by design

It contains `AUTH=PLAIN` but also contains `STARTTLS`. The latter indicates that the server supports an encrypted connection optionally, not necessarily enforced. So to my understanding the client is still able to use `AUTH=PLAIN` alone, without `STARTTLS` and therefore is also probably vulnerable to some kind of downgrade attack. Is my understanding correct and do such 'downgrade' attacks towards IMAP specifically exist?

I decided to try to determine if STARTTLS is enforced. What I tried so far is connect to the server using `telnet host 143` followed by a random, incorrect credential such as: `a1 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AGZvb2JhcgBiYXI=` and the server responded with: `a1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.` My guess is that connection encryption should be checked **BEFORE** authentication is checked and that therefore this response indicates that STARTTLS **is not** enforced by the server. I assume that the server would have otherwise not responded with 'auth failed' but instead something like 'encryption required'? Is this the correct way to check if STARTTLS is enforced remotely without credentials?

#### 2. Use of insecure hashing algorithm

Also the flags `AUTH=DIGEST-MD5` and `AUTH=CRAM-MD5` are used. MD5 is a known insecure hashing algorithm. Are these the only options IMAP has to offer or is there a better alternative?

#### 3. Information disclosure

Moreover it contains information leakage about the used software `Dovecot` and the used IMAP version `IMAP4rev1`.

#### Other

Based on the IMAP banner alone, and without knowing credentials can other security configuration tests be performed or recommendations be made? Can the banner be disabled in entirely to prevent this from leaking in the first place?

Comment: This is why I run IMAPS on port 993 instead of STARTTLS.  Encryption means never having to say you're sorry.

Answer (score 2):

> So to my understanding the client is still able to use AUTH=PLAIN alone, without STARTTLS and therefore is also probably vulnerable to some kind of downgrade attack.

Providing both STARTTLS and AUTH=PLAIN in the capability string says only that these capabilities are **available** and says nothing about required or optional. Showing AUTH=PLAIN in the initial capability string (i.e. outside of TLS) suggests though that the server is accepting authentication before STARTTLS. If authentication is only available after upgrade to TLS there usually is a LOGINDISABLED  in the initial capability string and AUTH=PLAIN only in the capability shown by the server after successful STARTTLS.

> Also the flags AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 and AUTH=CRAM-MD5 are used. MD5 is a known insecure hashing algorithm. Are these the only options IMAP has to offer or is there a better alternative?

IMAP4 has a flexible and extensible authentication mechanism. For example modern servers often supports AUTH=XOAUTH2 which enabled OAuth2 based authentication. Also, these challenge-response based options require special data storage at the server side (not the usual hashed password), so they might not be available at all.

> Moreover it contains information leakage about the used software Dovecot and the used IMAP version IMAP4rev1.

The IMAP version is not a leakage, similar to how the version string in the HTTP protocol (i.e. HTTP/1.1 or similar) is not a leakage. It is instead an information which protocol version is supported and thus similar to the other information in the CAPABILITY string.

As for the software name - this usually [can be configured](https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/core/#core_setting-login_greeting) similar to how it can be done with the server information in web servers. And, just because it says Dovecot you cannot actually sure that it is.

> Can the banner be disabled in entirely to prevent this from leaking in the first place?

The capabilities are relevant for the client to understand how to speak with the server. This is not information leakage - it is intended information sharing. The only "leakage" with the name of the server can usually be configured. But the details depend on the actual server, it is not specific to IMAP4 in general.

Comment: With 'the initial capability string (i.e. outside of TLS)' you mean my `telnet` test? It's not correct to take `AUTHENTICATIONFAILED` as, authentication was tried despite not having TLS, so TLS is not enforce by server? I think it's simply about code execution order. Which I don't know for Dovecot.

Comment: @BobOrtiz: There is no "dovecot behaves as follows ...". There are different versions of Dovecot, there are different configurations. It is not even clear if what you see is actually Dovecot or some server just claiming it to confuse others. It might even be a honeypot. And with "capability string" I mean what the server reports as its capability, either as answer to the capability command or as in your case already included in the initial server_greeting. Please see [the IMAPrev1 standard RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html) for details on the protocol.

Comment: I understand we can't be sure about the software used or actual vs advertised capabilities, but we can observe it's behaviour. Are you saying that the telnet test I showed basically doesn't give any information into wether STARTTLS is enforced or not? Because telnet surely does not use TLS (on port 143) and the error message clearly suggest the auth was attempted, so presumably without TLS. Or do I have some kind of brain error here?

Comment: @BobOrtiz: *"and the error message clearly suggest the auth was attempted"* - the error message says that authentication has failed. You assume that this message will only be sent if the authentication was attempted in the first place. A sane server would probably behave like you assume, but can you ensure that you've connected to a sane server? It is easy to write a server which sends this message no matter if authentication is actually done.

Answer (score 2):

> It contains AUTH=PLAIN but also contains STARTTLS. The latter indicates that the server supports an encrypted connection optionally, not necessarily enforced. So to my understanding the client is still able to use AUTH=PLAIN alone, without STARTTLS and therefore is also probably vulnerable to some kind of downgrade attack. Is my understanding correct and do such 'downgrade' attacks towards IMAP specifically exist?
>
> [...]
>
> My guess is that connection encryption should be checked BEFORE authentication is checked and that therefore this response indicates that STARTTLS is not enforced by the server

Downgrade attacks can exist for anything that falls back from TLS to non-TLS. But because it's the client that is the first to send sensitive information, and because it's usually only the client that verifies the server's TLS identity (certificate), it is the **client's** job – not the server's – to enforce TLS here.

If it was only the server that made TLS mandatory, an attacker could simply put a `stunnel` proxy in front of it and make clients connect to it instead – that's the same as with HTTP 'sslstrip' attacks. (The server doesn't validate clients, so it can't tell what's a real client and what's a MITM proxy.)

On the other hand, if the *client* made TLS mandatory – irrespective of whether it's STARTTLS or dedicated-port TLS – then the attacker couldn't do anything about it, because the client would no longer accept any substitutes anymore; a proxy that tries to force downgrade would just cause the connection attempt to fail.

You're right that the server *should* enforce TLS usage as well, but that's mostly to catch a small part of badly-configured clients.

> Also the flags AUTH=DIGEST-MD5 and AUTH=CRAM-MD5 are used. MD5 is a known insecure hashing algorithm.

Both of these auth mechanisms are obsolete, but the biggest problem is not just that they involve MD5 in general, but they both require the server to *store* just a plain MD5 hash of the user's password. (That is, you can't implement them while storing e.g. a PBKDF2 hash...)

As far as security over the network, though, both mechanisms use MD5 in a way that *I don't think* is subject to the same attacks as plain MD5 hashing (though I'm certainly no expert on that, but as far as I remember HMAC-MD5 still holds as long as the key is secret).

> Are these the only options IMAP has to offer or is there a better alternative?

IMAP generally supports any mechanism that's available through the SASL framework; the usual choice being PLAIN-over-TLS, of course, but other options such as SCRAM-SHA-# or GSSAPI (Kerberos) also exist.

(SCRAM and GSSAPI in fact have variants that support "TLS channel bindings" which effectively prevent downgrade attacks, to my understanding, but I don't think anyone implements them.)

> Moreover it contains information leakage about the used software Dovecot

This doesn't leak all that much – just the software in general, not even the version – and it can mostly be guessed from the server's behavior. Even if an attacker didn't know the software being used, they would likely just assume Dovecot as a very likely option due to its popularity.

> and the used IMAP version IMAP4rev1.

Every IMAP server made in the last few decades will be using IMAP4rev1; that's about as interesting as an HTTP server revealing that it is using HTTP/1.1, which is to say not interesting at all.

(And of course, the protocol version *has* to be revealed so that the client would **know how to interact with the server.**)